# Что здесь лучше, двоеточие или тире?

Tags: пунктуация

Также для членов ассоциации была организована экспозиция продукции «Спецтяжмаша»: цельнолитых пробок для шаровых кранов и головных образцов шаровых кранов с электогидроприводами производства Алексинского завода.

Answer (score 1):

Значение пояснения выражает классическое двоеточие или присоединительное тире, поэтому можно использовать любой вариант. В какой-то мере это зависит от контекста.

Если подробное перечисление продукции важно, то лучше поставить двоеточие. Если использовать тире, то однородный ряд будет  восприниматься в качестве дополнительной информации.

Comment: Спасибо за объяснение.

Answer (score 0):

Я бы поставила двоеточие, ведь вторая часть предложения раскрывает первую.

Comment: Спасибо большое.